# sas 9.0 Put two graphics

Tags: sas

I am facing a technical problem in SAS 9.2.

Here is an example code:

```
proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
reg y=Age x=height;
run;

proc sgplot data=sashelp.class;
scatter y=Age x=weight;
run;
```

I would like to put the 2 graphics together.

How can I do it easily?

Thanks.

Comment: 9.2 is well over a decade old, are you sure that's the version you have? Either way, what do you mean by 'put the 2 graphics together'?

Comment: I know... I would like to put the 1st graph next to the second. :)

Comment: Which output type are you using, listing, html, RTF, Excel, PDF? Commands are different for different sections. If you had a newer version, sgpanel is what you want but not sure that's in 9.2.

Comment: @mily, are you asking how to overlay the plots so its one graph?

Comment: Also please provide sample data so we can help replicate what you are seeking to do.

Comment: Yes Schilker. I would not like to overlay the plots. I just want to put the 2 graphics one next to other. The sample data is in SAS Library called : sashelp. It is a data wich is available for everybody (for training). Thanks